# How to update a row in an SQL table using ADO

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic

I have a page that displays a user table with user information. I want to be able to update a row in the table by clicking on a button at the end of each row. I am completely new to coding so if someone could help me and 'dumb' their answer down a little I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!

This is the code I have tried but don't seem to be able to get it to work.

```
<html>
<body>

<%
Dim conn, oRs, ID, sql
Set Conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
ID = Request.Form("ID")

If Request.Form("ID")="" then
  Set oRs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  oRs.open "SELECT * FROM tICTStaff WHERE ID ='" & ID & "'",Conn
  %>
  <form method="post" action="employeeUpdate.asp">
  <table>
  <%for each x in oRs.Fields%>
  <tr>
  <td><%=x.name%></td>
  <td><input name="<%=x.name%>" value="<%=x.value%>"></td>
  <%next%>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <br /><br />
  </form>
<%
Else
  sql="UPDATE table_name SET "
  sql=sql & "Forename ='" & Request.Form("Forename") & "',"
  sql=sql & "Surname ='" & Request.Form("Surname") & "',"
  sql=sql & "Active ='" & Request.Form("Active") & "',"
  sql=sql & "Address ='" & Request.Form("Address") & "',"
  sql=sql & "DOB ='" & Request.Form("DOB") & "',"
  sql=sql & " WHERE ID ='" & ID & "'"
  on error resume next
  Conn.Execute sql
  If err<>0 then
        Response.Write("Error updating Record!")
  Else
        Response.Write("Record " & ID & " was updated!")
  End If
End if
Conn.close
%>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=Page.index.asp?msg=The record has been updated!">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are mentioning ADO but tagged your question with "asp-classic". are you sure you are doing this in classic asp?

Comment: @ulluoink - I don't want you to write my code out for me, that would be great but I'm not really going to learn anything by doing that. I will copy the code I have tried into my original post, I forgot to do that when asking the initial question. I am writing it in ASP, not sure why it came up with ASP Classic, I must have done something wrong.

Comment: ok you ARE using asp-classic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems in your script.

1. **SQL injection!** Inform yourself about SQL injection and rewrite your entire script to avoid that! Do it first before you do anything else.
2. You are testing if `Request.Form("ID")` is `""`. But in your select you are using it although it is an empty string.
3. When using `on error resume next` in classic asp, you have to "switch off" error handling by using `on error goto 0`. Otherwise the `on error resume next` will be used for the rest of your script.
4. What are you trying to achieve by that `refresh` meta tag?

My suggestion to you is the following:

1. **Read about about SQL injection**.
2. Try to make a page which just lists the records from `tICTStaff`.
3. Then make a second page for editing those records. When you click on the edit button on the first page, navigate to your edit page and load that specific record from `tICTStaff`.
4. On your edit page, make a comfortable form and implement the update routine for that specific record.

On your overview site make links like so:

```
<%
Set oRs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
oRs.open "SELECT * FROM tICTStaff", Conn
do while not oRS.eof %>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><a href="update.asp?id=<%=oRS.fields("ID").value%>">link to detail/update page</a></td>
  </tr>
  <% oRS.movenext
loop %>
```

on your update.asp page load the record with the id from the querystring and display the form like so:

```
<%
dim myID : myID = request.querystring("ID")
if myID = "" then myID = request.form("ID")

' update record
if request.form("submit01") = "update" then
  sql = "update tICTStaff set fieldName1 = ? WHERE ID = ?"
  set cmd = server.createobject("adodb.command")
  cmd.activeconnection = Conn
  cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
  cmd.commandtext = sql

  cmd.parameters.append cmd.createparameter("fieldName1", adVarchar, , 512, request.form("fieldName1") )
  cmd.parameters.append cmd.createparameter("id", adInteger, , , myID )
  set oRS = cmd.execute
end if


' load record
sql = "select * from tICTStaff where id = ?"

set cmd = server.createobject("adodb.command")
cmd.activeconnection = Conn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.commandtext = sql
cmd.parameters.append cmd.createparameter("id", adInteger, , , myID )
set oRS = cmd.execute

' now you have a recordset with the record from tICTStaff with the ID
%>
<!-- display the form -->
<form name="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%=myID%>">

<!-- more fields to be edited -->
<input type="text" name="fieldName1" value="<%=oRS.fields("fieldName1").value%>">

<input type="submit" name="submit01" value="update">
</form>
```

**completely different solution (ajax based):**

As you want some kind of "mass update" function for the whole table, try jQuery with an AJAX call. So, on click of the button at the end of each row, you send an AJAX request to your ASP site with the values of the input fields *and* the ID of the record (the primary key of the `tICTStaff` table).

On the ASP page, you process the AJAX request and generate an UPDATE statement to update the `tICTStaff` table like so:

```
UPDATE tICTStaff
SET fldname1 = fldVal1, fldname2 = fldVal2
WHERE ID = postedID
```

To read about jQuery AJAX, have a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Comment: Ok cool, I will have a read on SQL Injection and rewrite my code. I already have everything else, I have a page which displays the information and I have an update page which has the update link available but no code behind it. All I'm struggling with is being able to edit a row of data.

Comment: do you mean the sql update clause or the possibility to "mass edit" a html table with some records?

Comment: I am currently showing a table full of data and I want to be able to edit for example a users name or their DOB. So I want to be able to click a button and edit some information in the row, but I'm struggling to get it to work. I used the update function before to update something specific but I have never written an update function to accept a unique identity for a row I want to update.

Comment: Thanks very much, I have taken your answer onboard and will go and have a read about jQuery. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Still having a little bit of trouble with this, I have created a new page where the update will take place. The original page now just shows the table with user information and has an update column with a link. The link then takes them to the update page were they are shown a form with 5 textboxes where I would like the users details to appear dependant upon which row the update button was clicked. I am struggling to get anything together or how to structure the code, I have had a go but I am just using ASP. I am unable to utilise Ajax!

Comment: @CodingNewbie *phew* now i updated my answer for the last time. i have written the code you was supposed to write.

Comment: You didn't need to write the whole code out for me, that wasn't what I was asking. I do appreciate you taking the time to do so and I will take the time to read through it and make sure I understand everything you've done.

Comment: I pretty much understand your code, but the one bit I don't quite understand is the initial code in the update.asp page. I am not asking the user to input an ID to select the row, I have a link at the end of each row that the user must click to load the row into a new page. So the bit I don't fully understand is from dim down to the first end if.

Comment: @CodingNewbie you give the id in the querystring look at the link on the overview site. then you put that id in a variable (myID). because you send the form by post in the next step you have to put that id in a hidden field to post it again to update.asp.

Comment: Everything is working brilliantly now thanks to you :) really appreicate your help. Thanks a lot!!